# Attempting to connect to VPN

Tags: openvpn

I use NordVPN. I clicked VPN Connections -> Configure VPN -> Add -> Import a saved VPN configuration file -> entered my username and passwrd and imported cacrt file but every time I try to connect it says timed out :( Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Start with basic network troubleshooting. Check IP address, verify VPN server has opened ports TCP 1723 and GRE, verify server has VPN account set up. Can you ping this IP address from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If UFW firewall is enabled, look at /var/log/ufw.log with text editor. Go to bottom of file and see if vpn ip address is being blocked. If so, add rule to ufw allowing in from that ip address.